# time.sleep for only a part of the code inside infinite while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, time, while-loop

I'm working with a code that analyzes frames from a live stream with OpenCV and if a condition is met saves the current frame to file.

The infinite loop to analyze the video frame by frame is something like this:

```
while True:
  ret,frame = stream.read()
  if conditionisMet :
     pil_image = Image.fromarray(frame)
     pil_image.save("/path/to/folder/image.jpg")
  cv2.imshow("LiveStream", frame)
```

What I want to add is that if the condition is met again too soon (20-30 sec) the image does not have to be saved and the while loop has to grab another frame and continue its work. I've tried with `time.sleep(30.0)` inside the if statement but it blocks the while loop waiting for the 30 sec to pass. Is there a way to use `time.sleep` in this case, or another method suitable for my needs?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like this:

```
last_grab=time.time()-30  # this to get things started
while True:
    if condition and time.time()-last_grab > 30:
        last_grab=time.time()
        # Do things here
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: `if condition == True` is silly and `&&` isn't a thing in Python. You mean `if condition and time.time() - last_grab > 30:`  (though I'd caution that using `time` instead of `datetime` here is silly)

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks for the catch... i've been going back and forth between awk and python all morning and got my languages all mixed up.

Comment: No worries, I do the same thing all the time. I removed the identity check though (`condition is True` should never pass)

Answer (score 1):

Just add a variable to keep track of your last saving time:

```
last_save_time = time.time()

while True:
  ret,frame = stream.read()

  if conditionisMet and time.time() - last_save_time() > 20:
     pil_image = Image.fromarray(frame)
     pil_image.save("/path/to/folder/image.jpg")

     # update last save time
     last_save_time = time.time()

  cv2.imshow("LiveStream", frame)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just capture the amount of time running then save image if greater than the given amount of time....

```
a = dt.now()
b = dt.now()
c = b - a
if c < x:
    do something
```